# how to get decode event params?

Tags: ethers.js

I have a smart contract that emits an event called `Transfer`
`emit Transfer(from, to, value);`

I want to know the values of `from`, `to`, and `value` of **each transaction** (by providing a transaction hash or something). How can I achieve this by ethers.js library (Currently, I'm on ethers 5.0)